# How do I pass solutions from recursive method call to calling method? (backtracking algorithm)

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I'm trying to implement a backtracking algorithm to balance weights on a scale. It's for university, so there are given weights I have to use (0, 2, 7, 20, 70, 200, 700). Weights can be placed on the scale multiple times to match the input. For example: input(80) -> result(20, 20, 20, 20) or input(16) -> result(7,7,2).
I have to use backtracking and recursion.

I have difficulties understanding how to do the backtracking if a proposal is wrong. I can only step back one step, but if the right solution requires two steps back my algorithm fails.

So my method isInvalid() is checking if the sum of all counterweights is higher than the input. If so, it will remove the last weight.
I guess this is my problem. For input(16) it produces (7,7,2) --> correct.
But for input(21) it never finishes, because it tries to add 20, and then tries to add 7. Then it will be over 21 and will remove 7, but it will never remove the 20.

/* This is my backtracking algorithm */

```
  public Proposal calc(Proposal proposal) {
    Proposal result;
    if(proposal.isInvalid()) return null;
    if(proposal.isSolution()) return proposal;

    for (int i : proposal.possibleNextSteps()) {
       Proposal newProposal = new Proposal(proposal.getWeight(), proposal.getCounterWeights());
       newProposal.apply(i);
       result = calc(newProposal);
       if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

/* this is the class Proposal (only required parts) */

```
public class Proposal {
private int weight;
private ArrayList<Integer> counterWeights;
private static Integer[] weights = {0, 2, 7, 20, 70, 200};

public Proposal(int weight, ArrayList<Integer> counterWeights) {
    this.weight = weight;
    this.counterWeights = counterWeights;
    Arrays.sort(weights, Collections.reverseOrder());
}

public boolean isInvalid() {
    if(counterWeights.stream().mapToInt(i -> i.intValue()).sum() > weight) {
        counterWeights.remove(counterWeights.size()-1);
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}


public boolean isSolution() {
    return counterWeights.stream().mapToInt(value -> value).sum() == weight;
}

public Integer[] possibleNextSteps() {
    return  weights;
}

public void apply(int option) {
    this.counterWeights.add(option);
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?
And also, is this the right way to reverse my array of weights?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I tried something different.
I changed this:

```
Proposal newProposal = new Proposal(proposal.getWeight()- proposal.getSum(), new ArrayList<>());
```

And this:

```
 public boolean isInvalid() {  
  return counterWeights.stream().mapToInt(value -> value).sum() > weight;
}
```

So now if I follow it step by step in debug mode, it is pretty much doing what I want it to do, but it does not pass the solutions from my recursion to my previous solution, so they do not add up to a final solution.
So basically I break down the problem in smaller problems (once i find a weight that fits, I'll call the method recursively with the difference between the total weight and the solution I've already found). But how do I pass the solutions to the calling method?

Comment: `"And also, is this the right way to reverse my array of weights?"` If you mean to sort the **Integer** array of weights in **descending** order then... yes.

Answer (score 0):

In the following implementation, a solution is an array of coefficients. a coefficient at index i is the number of times the weight at position i appears in the solution.

Note that you can have several solutions giving the same total weight, this implementation gives them all. It's easy to change it to return only the first solution found.

The recursive methode `void solve(int weight, int n, int total)` tries for index `n` all integers for which the total weight is no greater than the target weight.

```
public class Solver {
    private final int[] weights;
    private int[] current;
    private final List<int[]> solutions = new ArrayList<>();

    public Solver(int...weights) {
        this.weights = weights;
    }

    public int[][] solve(int weight) {
        current = new int[weights.length];
        solutions.clear();
        solve(weight, 0, 0);
        return solutions.toArray(new int[solutions.size()][]);
    }

    public void printSolution(int[] solution) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < solution[i]; ++j) {
                System.out.print(weights[i] + " ");
                total += weights[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" total: " + total);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void solve(int weight, int n, int total) {
        if (n >= current.length) {
            if (total == weight) {
                solutions.add(current.clone());
            }
        } else {
            solve(weight, n+1, total);
            while (total < weight) {
                ++current[n];
                total += weights[n];
                solve(weight, n+1, total);
            }
            current[n] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it isn't really using backtracking, if I understand the code right?! I have to use a backtracking algorithm to solve the problem